# How to solve the following limit problem

Tags: calculus, limits

$$ \lim_{x\to 0} \left({1+3}{x^2}\right)^{\frac{2 \csc x}{x}+5 \cot x}$$

How to apply l'Hôpital's rule?

Comment: It  doesn't appear that you've digested the problem before posting here.  The expression, as it appears now, is not a ratio and thus is not amenable to a direct application of l'Hôpital's rule.  The first idea that comes to my mind is taking the logarithm (since $\log$ is continuous, the limit of the logarithm will likely be the logarithm of the limit, unless the limit is zero).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why you want to use l'Hôpital's rule. I prefer:
$$
\begin{align}
(1+3x^2)^{\frac 2 {x\sin(x)}+\frac {5\cos(x)} {\sin(x)}}&=\exp(\ln(1+3x^2)(\frac 2 {x\sin(x)}+\frac {5\cos(x)} {\sin(x)}))\\
&=_{x\to 0}\exp((3x^2+o(x^2))\frac {2+5x\cos(x)}{x\sin(x)})\\
&=_{x\to 0}\exp((3x^2+o(x^2))\frac {2+o(1)}{x^2+o(x^2)})\\
&=_{x\to 0}\exp(6+o(1))
\end{align}
$$
Then,
$$\lim_{x\to 0}(1+3x^2)^{\frac 2 {x\sin(x)}+\frac {5\cos(x)} {\sin(x)}}=e^6$$

Comment: I think it make very useful...Thanks...

Comment: @ChinnapparajR What is this method? What is $O(x^2)$?